# Undefined index: when using session_start() in another browser or postman

Tags: php

First I hope all people here are good!

I am learning PHP and want to pass one variable between two PHP files by using session_start(), I used it …But got a strange result!
when I access the link of php file in web chrome browser I got the right result because I start the session of course from chrome but when I accessed the page2.php on postman or firefox I got undefined index error!

the first file page1.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$Sort_Number = 100;

        $_SESSION['Sort_Number'] = "$Sort_Number";

?>
```

in second file page2.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$Sort_Number = $_SESSION['Sort_Number'];
echo $Sort_Number;
?>
```

I couldn’t figure out what is the issue here! why in web browser I got right result but when use postman not get it!

this error I got:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: Sort_Number in
<b>/home/u277252404/domains/1234.tech/public_html/test/page2.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
```

How can I let page2.php to save the variable even if I accessed the page2.php from another browser or from postman?

Comment: A session does not persist across two distinct browsers. Are you accessing both `page1.php` and then `page2.php` in Firefox? Postman is going to be a different issue - I don't believe cookies returned from one request are sent automatically on the next. You'll need to specify that yourself.

Comment: sessions are relevant to the browser - they cannot be shared by different browsers

Comment: So you mean `session_start` is store in cookies..Yes if in cookies will be in the same browse...that's right!...but how can I solve it :)

Comment: PHP sessions cannot be used to pass data between distinct browsers. If that is your requirement, you need to choose a different solution. If you.need advice as to alternative solutions, you'll need to post more information, but I suspect it'll be considered off topic for SO.

Comment: fubar, what I want is to let Arduino get the data from MySQL table database using HTTP request. One PHP file will search in data base for sort number and then send it to Arduino or let Arduino get it. that what I want

Comment: Can you not pass the sort number as a URL parameter? Then anyone with the same link will have the same value, irrespective of browser and session.

Comment: you are right from this point! thanks to remind me..I was thinking about it..so What is the best solution for what I want?

Answer (score 0):

firstly check session if it exists like

```
if( $_SESSION['Sort_Number']){
    // our code here
 }else{
  //session did not have value 
  }
```

Comment: That'll still return an `undefined index` warning. You need to use `isset()`, `array_key_exists()`, or `??` (null coalesce).

Comment: Thanks @Birhan Nega, the session is exist because I can see '''100''' value in page2.php in the same browser. but the problem if I opened in another browser. Am I right?

Comment: @m-saeed if you opened another browser, the session will not be there unless you set it the start of your app